# React native not connecting to apollo server even use ApolloProvider

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am having issues with connect react-native project with apollo server.

I followed instruction on Apollo Client https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started but still having issues get data from apollo server.

Here is my `server.js` from backend:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");
const {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault,
} = require("apollo-server-core");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Post {
    id: Int!
    title: String
    description: String
    author: String
    images: String
    likes: Int
    createdAt: String
  }

  type Query {
    posts: [Post]
  }
`;

const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Testing",
    description: "post 1",
    author: "Nate",
    image: "",
    likes: 0,
    createdAt: "2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Post 2",
    description: "post 2",
    author: "Nathan",
    image: "",
    likes: 10,
    createdAt: "2021-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    posts: () => posts,
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  csrfPrevention: true,
  cache: "bounded",
  plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true })],
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

and here is my `App.js` from react-native project:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  from,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import List from "./components/List";

const errorLink = onError(({ graphqlErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphqlErrors) {
    graphqlErrors.map(({ message, location, path }) => {
      console.log(`GraphQL error ${message}`);
    });
  }
});

const link = from([errorLink, new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:4000/" })]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/",
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: link,
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <List />
      </View>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

`List.js`:

```
...
const GET_POSTS = gql`
  query GetPosts {
    posts {
      id
      title
      description
      author
      image
      likes
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;

const List = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_POSTS);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data: ", data);
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Can someone tell me where did I do wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Anyone can help me with this ????

Comment: Need some one help me to solve this